# How to open report in PDF inside in current browser windows, not a new browser windows from reporting services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

[SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services) allow to open report in PDF with following URL access:

```
http://localhost:8080/reportserver?/MyReports/Report1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF
```

but the PDF will be open in a new browser window. How to set proper parameter and open it in current browser window?

Comment: If you are talking about just adding another parameter to the querystring, it cannot be done that way. The details you give are quite vague - how is your browser page structured - what language/technology are you using? I know how to do it using ASP.NET, the method may be portable to other web technologies.

Comment: Ｉ use IE 8 on XP for testing. Access report service in browser directly. What I want is to access it in a asp web site and make sure it is working. Then try to use it for Silverlight with a htmlviewer in a Iframe. I use C# for this case. If you can send me the example with source code, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok cool, we have something to start with.
It was tricky to work out how to do this (it took a reasonable number of hours), and i'm not at liberty to give you the exact code (as it belongs to the people i wrote it for), but i can give you the method for doing it. With this method you should be able to nicely host the aspx page inside a silverlight control, although you may have to think about the physical size of your rendered report it may be a little tight on space when hosted like that.

- in your aspx page, create an HttpWebRequest, the url should point to the appropriate reports folder in the SSRS installation
- create the querystring which contains the report parameters, convert it to a byte[] using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameterString)
- write that byte array to the RequestStream of the HttpWebRequest you created
- do a request.GetResponse(), assign it's output to a new HttpWebResponse object (let's call it the ssrsResponse)
- get the response object of the current page (let's call it currentResponse)
- set the content type of currentResponse to Application/PDF
- add the `Content-Disposition` header to currentResponse, set its value to `inline;filename=[insert filename here]`
- read the response stream from ssrsResponse and write it to currentResponse (this is just an exercise in transferring the contents of one stream to another)
- call `currentResponse.End()`

Comment: Thank you. So I want to create a http handler at server side only for reporting service url, say ReportingService.ashx. The all I need to do is to implement above guide in public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {...}. But I am not familiar with httphandler. Could you give me the demo code for your guide?

Comment: No, there is no HttpHandler required. This is all done within a single aspx page.

Comment: Thank you, slugster. I have created a httphandler to implement your suggestion. It works fine in IE, but not in FF, it still shows the download popup and then display the pdf in another window(pdf reader). Not sure why. any idea?